# How to set password in community version of Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

How can I set the password for a non-enterprise instance of Memgraph? I'm using community edition. I'm not looking for role-based access control. I'd just like to have at least some level of protection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic authentication is supported in the non-enterprise version.

You can create a password-protected account with the following query:

```
CREATE USER user_name [IDENTIFIED BY 'password'];
```

For example:

```
CREATE USER kwriter IDENTIFIED BY '8LJBhbu26d';
```